# C++ validity check

Tags: c++

I currently have this I'm trying to have it check to see if the value is less than 1. if it is I want it to prompt for a new entry until the value meets the requirements.

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer value: ";
cin >> input_value;
while (input_value <= 0)
    cout << "Invalid Value" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer value: ";
    cin >> input_value;
```

Comment: indentation doesn't create block, `{/*..*/}` does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your issue is; it may be helpful if you could clarify what you are having trouble with, however if you want to the value to be less than one you would use

```
double input value;
cout << "Input value: ";
cin >> input_value;
while (input_value < 1) {
cout << "Error; value must not be less than 1" << endl;
cout << "Input value: ";
cin >> input_value;
}
```

Comment: Your error text doesn't fit the condition. It will only be printed if the entered value is indeed less than one. "must _not_" would probably be better.

Comment: sorry i want the value to be 1 or greater. if the value is less than 1 want the loop to prompt again until the value entered is at least 1.

Comment: This should be able to do that as the loop will only trigger if the value is less than one; if the value is one the loop will not trigger and continue forward